# Raspberry pi pico I2S work on byte by byte transfer but not on buffer read writes

Tags: arduino-ide, audio, speaker, raspberrypi-pico

I'm using a raspberry pi pico W and testing audio loopback (microphone to speaker in a loop) using INMP441 microphone and MAX98357 amp board.

Followed functions from this page https://arduino-pico.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i2s.html

I arrived at this code:

```
#include <I2S.h>

I2S* I2SOutputDevice = nullptr;
I2S* I2SInputDevice = nullptr;
#define I2S_SAMPLE_RATE 44100
#define I2S_BITS 24
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 256
#define I2S_BUFFER_SIZE 1024


uint8_t* data;


// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {

    I2SOutputDevice = new I2S(OUTPUT);
    I2SOutputDevice->setBCLK(16);
    I2SOutputDevice->setDATA(18);
    I2SOutputDevice->setBitsPerSample(I2S_BITS);
    I2SOutputDevice->setFrequency(I2S_SAMPLE_RATE);
    I2SOutputDevice->setSysClk(I2S_SAMPLE_RATE);
    I2SOutputDevice->setBuffers(2, BUFFER_LENGTH);
    
    pinMode(19,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(19,HIGH);


    I2SInputDevice = new I2S(INPUT);
    I2SInputDevice->setBCLK(20);
    I2SInputDevice->setDATA(22);
    I2SInputDevice->setBitsPerSample(I2S_BITS);
    I2SInputDevice->setFrequency(I2S_SAMPLE_RATE);
    I2SInputDevice->setSysClk(I2S_SAMPLE_RATE);
    I2SInputDevice->setBuffers(2, BUFFER_LENGTH);

    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT);

    data = new uint8_t[I2S_BUFFER_SIZE];
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(1000);

    I2SOutputDevice->begin();
    I2SInputDevice->begin();
}


// the loop function runs over and over again until power down or reset
void loop() {


    // does not work
    size_t actuallyRead = I2SInputDevice->readBytes(data, I2S_BUFFER_SIZE);
    I2SOutputDevice->write(data, actuallyRead);
    


    // works
    
    //int32_t L, R;
    //I2SInputDevice->read24(&L, &R);
    //I2SOutputDevice->write24(L, R);

}
```

As indicated in the code reading one sample at a time and writing works fine I can hear on speaker what I speak into the microphone.

however if I go the buffer read and write route all I get is noise form the speaker that does not react or correspond to any microphone input .

If I add a serial print to see how many bytes were read then it is a positive number the same as size of the buffer, so it is reading data but playback is missing in this case

what am I doing wrong?

Bonus question: INMP441 seem to have very low sensitivity , you have to speak very close to it which is nearly impractical , is this normal?

Comment: Please extend your test code to print the number of read bytes in each loop. Are you aware that both I²C transfers and serial transmissions need time, and therefore the playback can have another sampling rate?

Comment: I did print the read bytes and its always the full size of the buffer